# weblogic 11gr2 taking too long for update data on database

Tags: oracle11g, weblogic11g, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have two oracle forms and reports server.

1. oracle forms and reports server 11gr1 (weblogic 10.3.5.0)
2. oracle forms and reports server 11gr2 (weblogic 10.3.6.0)

both are connected with same database but at time of update data on database new server(11gr2) taking twice or more then that, time for data update compare to old one (11gr1).

I have checked deployed form and procedure inside that form they are same.

further analysis:

form has a PROCEDURE which update data in database and do some IO operation.

found that this PROCEDURE takes more time on 11gr2 compare to 11gr1.

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache? What do you find from weblogic logs?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, it was slow due to SYNCHRONIZE was used inside of loop in plsql code in FORM.